# Unable to create db2 table with DATE data type

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 9.7 (LUW) in a windows server, in which multiple DBs are available in a single DB instance. I just found that in one of these DBs, I am unable to add a column with DATE data type, during table creation or altering. The column been added is getting changed to timestamp instead.

[image]

Any help on this will be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Check out your [Oracle Compatibility setting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html)

Depending on that setting a date is interpreted as Timestamp(0) like in your example.
Because these settings take effect if the database has been created after setting the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR registry variable your database can show a different behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is set as DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA. This is set at an instance level and not at database level, right? In the other database in the same server/ instance, there is no issue with the DATE datatype.

Comment: @Manoj This depends on the [date_compat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0054912.html) parameter setting of the database. This parameter can be set upon the database creation only (depending on the `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR` **registry variable** setting at that time), and can't be changed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. So, I am stuck then! What if I need to store date value in dd-mm-yyyy format in a column? I can do that with a varchar(10) column. But, how can i ensure that the value been stored in this column is of dd-mm-yyyy format?

Comment: You could add a constraint on your column to stop it holding non-zero time values. You would need to do the same on Oracle right?

Comment: Out of interest, Db2 stores dates and timestamps as decimal numbers in BCD format (YYYYMMDD etc). So asking to store in `dd-mm-yyyy` format does not make much sense.  Still you could use a CHAR(10) and an constraint that is it a valid date of that format.